# Facebook Graph API Insights Requests Return Zero

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am attempting to retrieve the number of fans for my Page via the PHP SDK. Here is all of my code so far.

```
$fbSession = \Facebook\FacebookSession::newAppSession(self::APP_ID, self::APP_SECRET);
$fbLikesResponse = null;
try {
    $fbLikesRequest = new \Facebook\FacebookRequest($fbSession, 'GET', '/{myRealPageIDGoesHere}/insights/page_fans');
    $fbLikesResponse = $fbLikesRequest->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
} catch (\Facebook\FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    $resp = new \stdClass();
    $resp->error = $ex;
    return $resp;
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

//Add items to response and to store
var_dump($fbLikesResponse);
```

I never get authentication/authorizaiton errors, but the data response value is always just 0. I can see on the Facebook page itself that there are more than 0 likes.

I really don't want to have to resort to screen-scraping to obtain how many likes my Facebook page has. Any idea why I only get 0s?

Clarification- this is for a server-side call for an analytics engine. No user authentication is involved, so I'm trying to figure out how to get hit the {node}/insights/page_fans endpoint without faking some sort of user login.

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Which access token are you using? To fetch your page's insights you should be using a page access token, not an app access token

Comment: @Igy How can I get a page access token without authenticating as a user? This is a request coming solely from my server, not on behalf of a user.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens - you can't generally access the API on behalf of a user without an access token from that user (same with pages, can't access a page's private data without an admin of the page giving you permission to)

Comment: Let's say my Facebook user profile is granted access to the page as an admin. Could I then manually generate an OAuth request on the PHP side on behalf of my user in order to get a page token? Obviously this isn't ideal because my account details would be mebedded in the code, but I can't think of another way to get this to work.